# Property returns undefined typescript

Tags: typescript

Why does this:

```
class T { 
    test: "print me"
}

const t = new T();
document.write(t.test);
```

Returns undefined? How can I print out "print me"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
test: "print me";
```

declares a property `test` of **type** "print me" (i.e. the only allowed  value of the variable is "print me"), but it doesn't initialize it.

You want

```
test = "print me";
```

which declares and initializes a property with the value "print me". The compiler infers its type to `string`.